# Where to keep the javascript code of a partial view (which can be included using @include) in blade templating?

Tags: html, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I have a structure where a view.blade.php extends a layout.blade.php. Layout blade has @yield('js').The view page which extends layout blade needs to include a partial form which has some javascript. I have a confusion about where to keep the javascript code for the form so that it is yielded in the layout. Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please include some code (even generic one) that showcases your current structure. Your description of the problem is a little abstract and it's hard to give answers based on that alone.

Answer (score 0):

its really easy with laravel blade you can put javascript for partials blade file 
when you will call them they will automatically included in layout.blade.php here is example of your all views.

**layout.blade.php**

```
@yield('js')
```

**partial.blade.php**

```
@section('js')
  <script src="patial/jsfile.js"></script>
@stop
```

**view.blade.pp**

```
@extends("layout")

@include("partial")
```

this will work like charm and really simple.